# Call REST endpoint using webclient which has both PathVariable and RequestParam

Tags: spring-boot, rest, spring-webclient

I have the following endpoint, which needs to be called from webclient. date is red using @PathVariable and name is red using @RequestParam annotations.

```
/api/v1/names/officialNameByDate/{date}?name=empName
```

Is the following usage correct?

```
String response = webclient.get()
                 .uri(uriBuilder -> uriBuilder
                    .path("/api/v1/names/officialNameByDate/{date}")
                    .queryParam("name", empName)
                .build(date))
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(String.class).block();
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use both Path variable and Request Param.

```
    webClient.get()
      .uri(uriBuilder - > uriBuilder
      .path("/products/{id}/attributes/{attributeId}")
      .queryParam("name", "AndroidPhone")
      .queryParam("color", "black")
      .build(2, 13))
      .retrieve()
      .bodyToMono(String.class)
      .block();

verifyCalledUrl("/products/2/attributes/13?color=black");
```

See above code as an example.